# split string into the string and digits

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to split this string (`incoming_string`) to digits and string to the next view (`result`):

`incoming_string = '02, 102, 702New York'  # Also possible incoming strings: '06, 25Jerusalem' or '34Saint Luise'`

`result = {'New York': ['02', '102', '702']}`

I'm found this approcach, but I think this is not a best way:

```
import re


digits = re.findall('\d+', incoming_string)  # ['02', '102', '702']
strings = re.findall('[a-z, A-Z]+', incoming_string)[-1]  # 'New York'
```

By best way I mean a  most concise, understandable and pythonic way, preferable without imports.
All symbols are the same encoding (ascii)

Comment: I think it's a pretty general solution. Looks good to me. Just create a dict like `{strings: digits}`.

Comment: Not best in what sense, can you please define what you are looking for?

Comment: @SerialLazer most concise, understandable and pythonic way, preferable without imports

Comment: Will you be dealing solely with ASCII letters? If not consider what would happen for example for `Saint-Étienne` or any other name with diacritics.

Comment: Without `import re`, you would technically end up writing some form of the regex-source-code (albeit specific to your use-case). Reinventing the wheel, especially a library thats provided and widely used is a huge anti-pattern honestly.

Comment: @Daweo Yes, added this remark to the question

Comment: @SerialLazer Not all programmer falmiliar with regex, even I was googling before to using '\d+' (digits) and [a-z, A-Z]. For me easier to just read a few lines of code with some builtins python methods. But you are right, this is reinventing of wheels somethimes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trouble is finding the index where the list stops and the key value starts. We can make a function that helps us find the first "non-list character". Then it's a matter of splitting the string in two using that index, after which we can split the first part into a list using the `", "` delimiter.

```py
def get_first_non_list_char_index(incoming_string):
    for i, c in enumerate(incoming_string):
        if c not in "1234567890, ":
            return i

incoming_string = "02, 102, 702New York"
char_index = get_first_non_list_char_index(incoming_string)

result = {incoming_string[char_index:]: incoming_string[:char_index].split(", ")}
```

`result = {'New York': ['02', '102', '702']}`

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

`(\d{2}), (\d{3}), (\d{3})(.+)`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/jLb5rP/1)

Code:

```
import re

incoming_string = '02, 102, 702New York'
print(re.sub("(\d{2}), (\d{3}), (\d{3})(.+)", "{\\4: [\\1, \\2, \\3]}", incoming_string))
```

ouput:

`{New York: [02, 102, 702]}`

Answer (score 0):

`import`less solution as requested:

```
incoming_string = '02, 102, 702New York'
letters = ''.join(i for i in incoming_string if i.isalpha() or i.isspace())
numbers = ''.join(i for i in incoming_string if i.isdigit() or i.isspace())
result = {letters.strip(): numbers.split()}
print(result)
```

Output:

```
{'New York': ['02', '102', '702']}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `re.split` to get this result:

```
sl=['02, 102, 702New York',  
'06, 25Jerusalem',
'34Saint Luise']

import re

for s in sl:
    fields=re.split(r'(?<=\d)(?=[a-zA-Z])', s, maxsplit=1)
    print(s, "=>", {fields[1]:re.split(r',[ ]*',fields[0])})
```

Prints:

```
02, 102, 702New York => {'New York': ['02', '102', '702']}
06, 25Jerusalem => {'Jerusalem': ['06', '25']}
34Saint Luise => {'Saint Luise': ['34']}
```